# How to decrypt / break enigma-encrypted ciphertext with given configuraton?

Tags: enigma

I'm new here--seriously I don't know anything, but my close friend sending me a code and I must solve it.

The code uses Rotor III, V, VIII;  starting point ABC; reflector BB; and pair OA LU.

Can someone give me an example and its procedure about solving a question/code using those rules?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the configuration of the machine you can easily decrypt the message. All you need is an enigma machine, I found one of several emulators online: [Enigma emulator](https://cryptii.com/enigma-machine).